# Как написать обработчик события во Flask

Tags: flask

у меня есть простой набор радиокнопок, написанных через шаблонизатор

```
{% for g in gv %}
<p><input type="radio" name="group" value={{g}}>{{g}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Как написать обработку кликов на этих кнопках и вывести в label какая кнопка нажата?